# Do something after a row is added in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

Is there a equivalent event for add row similar to the [remove](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/remove) event in kendo grid. [Edit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit) event doesn't seem to be helpful as it fires before the add confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the RequestEnd and/or RequestStart events on the datasource:

```
.Events(events => events.RequestEnd("requestEnd").RequestStart("requestStart"))
```

Then in the function, check the type:

```
    function requestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type == "update" || e.type == "create") {
        doStuff();
    }
}

function requestStart(e) {
    if (e.type == "add") {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```